# Confusion regarding formula of positive feedback

Tags: control, control-system

Please check the attached snap especially the yellow highlighted "plus" sign . According to my understanding it should be "negative" because it is case of positve feedback as shown in second snap where relevant block diagram is shown

[image]

[image]

Comment: We have negative fedback when the loop contains one or three (or...) phase inversions. In the circuit under discussion I can identify one minus sign within he loop.

Answer (score 0):

It seems correct. By using superposition principle, you ignore the R(s) input and construct the equation from Figure 3.1:

$$ [-C_D(s)H(s)*G_1(s) + D(s)] * G_2(s) = C_D(s) $$

Then apply some algebra manipulation and you should arrive to this:

$$ \frac{G_2(s)}{1 + H(s)G_1(s)G_2(s)} = \frac{C_D(s)}{D(s)} $$

Comment: In fact, IT IS correct!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to consider the negative sign in the left-most summing point: -

[image]

In your formula it must be positive for negative feedback. I don't understand why you think it should be a negative sign. Do the math.